# How to derive Eq.(1) in Prof. A Leggett's lecture note?

Tags: anderson-localization

I came across a [lecture note](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys598PTD/fa2013/L5.pdf) on weak localisation by Prof. A. J. Leggett. In this note, he wrote down his first equation as follows: $$\sigma = \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 0} \lim_{q\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{i\omega}\frac{\delta j(q\omega)}{\delta A(q\omega)} = \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 0} \lim_{q\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{i\omega}\langle[j_q(t),j_q(0)]\rangle_{\omega}\\ = \int^{\infty}_0 dt\int\int\frac{dr dr'}{V}\langle[j(rt),j(r'0)]\rangle.$$ I understand the first two equalities. But how do I prove the third one? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $\langle \rangle_{\omega}$ ? What is $V$ ?

Comment: @Trimok: Thanks for your response. $<X>_{\omega}$ is the Fourier transform of the average of $X$. $V$ is volume. You can click the link to have a look at the whole lecture.

Comment: Apparently, it is known as the Kubo formula for conductivity. The last equality is a double spatial Fourier transform on $j(q,t)$ and $j(q'=q,0)$. I don't understand the supplementary factor $\frac{i\omega}{V}$, but following this [paper](http://timstadelmann.de/conductivity.pdf), formulae $(B.37)(B.38)(B.39)$, this is precisely the coefficient of proportionnality between the polarization $\pi(\omega)$ and the current $j(\omega)$. So maybe, there is an error in your lecture note

Comment: @Trimok: Thanks a lot. I'll read the paper. I also think there is something wrong in that equation. The factor $1/\omega$ seems lost.